# Writing a more concise lambda in Python

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I am trying to work with Pandas on some data problems and have come to a point where I am writing code like this:

```
groups.segment = groups.topic.map(lambda x: 'friends' if 'friend' in str(x) else x)
groups.segment = groups.topic.map(lambda x: 'friends' if 'bro' in str(x) else x)
groups.segment = groups.topic.map(lambda x: 'friends' if 'girls' in str(x) else x)
```

I would like to write it in a more concise way way where I don't have to have a bunch of copy and paste code. A little bit new to python so not sure how to make it better. Any help appreciated.

Something along the lines of:

```
groups.segment = groups.segment.map(lambda x: 'friends' if 'bro' or 'girls' or 'friend' in str(x) else x)
```

Is there a way to do this ?

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Look into the `any` built-in function.

Answer (score 5):

It's probably better not to use `lambda` here:

```
def mapper(x)
    if any(y in str(x) for y in ('friend', 'bro', 'girls')):
        return 'friends'
    return x

groups.segment = groups.topic.map(mapper)
```

You can use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) here which returns `True` when at least one of the passed values is `True`.

Answer (score 1):

```
lambda x: 'friends' if 'bro' in str(x) or 'girls' in str(x) or 'friend' in str(x) else x
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid `map` and `lambda` altogether and use `isin()`, which ends up working more like the typical Python idiom of `if item in ['a', 'b', 'c']:`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'relationship': ['friends', 'friend', 'bro', 'girls']})
df
Out[3]: 
  relationship
0      friends
1       friend
2          bro
3        girls

is_synonym = df.relationship.isin(['friend', 'bro', 'girls'])
df['relationship2'] = df['relationship'].copy()
df.loc[is_synonym, 'relationship2'] = 'friends'
df
Out[15]: 
  relationship relationship2
0      friends       friends
1       friend       friends
2          bro       friends
3        girls       friends
```